# recvfrom hangs on certain addresses C

Tags: c, sockets

I am creating an implementation of trace route using socket programming in C, which simply creates new requests with an incrementing TTL field. The code shown below works relatively well, however when trying to contact google for example, the recvfrom function hangs for some addresses but not others, stopping the algorithm from completing and leaving the program running infinitely. This is what I have so far:

```
int traceroute(char *srcaddress) {
int exists = 0;
int sendsock, recvsock, portno, portno2, *ttl, i = 1;
portno = 33434;
portno2 = 33435;
struct sockaddr_in recvaddr, sendaddr, curraddr, target;
char *currAddr = myaddress;
char message[512];
char *probemessage = "hello";
target.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(srcaddress);
target.sin_family = AF_INET;
target.sin_port = 33436;
ttl = &i;
recvaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
recvaddr.sin_port = portno;
recvaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
sendaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
sendaddr.sin_port = portno2;
sendaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
while (i <= 30) {

    sendsock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    recvsock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_ICMP);
    if (sendsock < 0) {
        exists = 1;

        fprintf(stderr, "could not create sending socket");
    }
    if (recvsock < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "could not create receiving socket");
    }
    setsockopt(sendsock, IPPROTO_IP, IP_TTL, ttl, sizeof(ttl));

    struct timeval tv;

    tv.tv_sec = 1;  /* 30 Secs Timeout */
    tv.tv_usec = 0;  // Not init'ing this can cause strange errors

    setsockopt(recvsock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (char *)&tv,sizeof(struct timeval));


    int len = sizeof(curraddr);

    if (bind(recvsock, (struct sockaddr *) &recvaddr, sizeof(recvaddr))
            < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "could not bind");
    }
    if (sendto(sendsock, probemessage, strlen(probemessage), 0,
            (struct sockaddr*) &target, sizeof(target)) < 0) {
        puts("did not send[100] data");
    }
    if (recvfrom(recvsock, message, sizeof(message), 0,
            (struct sockaddr*) &curraddr, (socklen_t*) &len) < 0) {
        puts("no data receievd");
    }
    currAddr = strdup(inet_ntoa(curraddr.sin_addr));
    if (strcmp(currAddr, srcaddress) == 0) {
        break;
    }
    close(sendsock);
    close(recvsock);

    printf("hops: %d address %s \n", i, currAddr);

    i++;
}
if (*ttl == 30 && currAddr != srcaddress) {
    exists = 0;
} else {
    exists = 1;
}
return exists;
```

}

In the google example, it will hang when the current address is 62.72.134.198

**UPDATE**

I have now implemented a timeout, however the algorithm still does not get past these addresses and does not seem to detect the intermediate nodes. I have crossed referenced with the existing Linux implementation of trace route and it does not seem to be able to receive any data even when the number of hops is equal to that required to reach the destination address.

Here is the strace of the binary:

```
execve("./a.out", ["./a.out"], [/* 18 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x9b1c000
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mmap2(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb7797000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=95669, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 95669, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0xb777f000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\3\0\1\0\0\0\220\210\1\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1807496, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 1814236, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0xb75c4000
mmap2(0xb7778000, 20480, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1b3000) = 0xb7778000
mmap2(0xb777d000, 7900, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb777d000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb75c3000
set_thread_area({entry_number:-1 -> 6, base_addr:0xb75c3940, limit:1048575, seg_32bit:1, contents:0, read_exec_only:0, limit_in_pages:1, seg_not_present:0, useable:1}) = 0
mprotect(0xb7778000, 12288, PROT_READ)  = 0
mprotect(0x8049000, 4096, PROT_READ)    = 0
mprotect(0xb77be000, 4096, PROT_READ)   = 0
munmap(0xb777f000, 95669)               = 0
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 3
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_ICMP) = 4
setsockopt(3, SOL_IP, IP_TTL, [1], 4)   = 0
setsockopt(4, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8) = 0
bind(4, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(39554), sin_addr=inet_addr("0.0.0.0")}, 16) = 0
sendto(3, "hello", 5, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(40066), sin_addr=inet_addr("192.168.1.244")}, 16) = 5
recvfrom(4, "E\300\0=+_\0\0@\1\311h\300\250\1\364\300\250\1\364\3\3\16Q\0\0\0\0E\0\0!"..., 512, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(0), sin_addr=inet_addr("192.168.1.244")}, [16]) = 61
brk(0)                                  = 0x9b1c000
brk(0x9b3d000)                          = 0x9b3d000
fstat64(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 3), ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb7796000
write(1, "TEST PASSED\n", 12)           = 12
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 5
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_ICMP) = 6
setsockopt(5, SOL_IP, IP_TTL, [1], 4)   = 0
setsockopt(6, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8) = 0
bind(6, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(39554), sin_addr=inet_addr("0.0.0.0")}, 16) = 0
sendto(5, "hello", 5, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(40066), sin_addr=inet_addr("204.79.197.200")}, 16) = 5
recvfrom(6, "E\300\0=\234A\0\0@\1Yy\300\250\1\1\300\250\1\364\v\0I\323\0\0\0\0E\0\0!"..., 512, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(0), sin_addr=inet_addr("192.168.1.1")}, [16]) = 61
close(5)                                = 0
close(6)                                = 0
write(1, "hops: 1 address 192.168.1.1 \n", 29) = 29
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 5
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_ICMP) = 6
setsockopt(5, SOL_IP, IP_TTL, [2], 4)   = 0
setsockopt(6, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8) = 0
bind(6, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(39554), sin_addr=inet_addr("0.0.0.0")}, 16) = 0
sendto(5, "hello", 5, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(40066), sin_addr=inet_addr("204.79.197.200")}, 16) = 5
recvfrom(6, "E\0\0008\0\0\0\0\376\0013\264>H\210,\300\250\1\364\v\0\215\245\0\0\0\0E\0\0!"..., 512, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(0), sin_addr=inet_addr("62.72.136.44")}, [16]) = 56
close(5)                                = 0
close(6)                                = 0
write(1, "hops: 2 address 62.72.136.44 \n", 30) = 30
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 5
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_ICMP) = 6
setsockopt(5, SOL_IP, IP_TTL, [3], 4)   = 0
setsockopt(6, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8) = 0
bind(6, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(39554), sin_addr=inet_addr("0.0.0.0")}, 16) = 0
sendto(5, "hello", 5, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(40066), sin_addr=inet_addr("204.79.197.200")}, 16) = 5
recvfrom(6, "E\0\0`{\n\0\0\374\1\271@>H\211m\300\250\1\364\v\0B/?\363\307\260E\0\0!"..., 512, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(0), sin_addr=inet_addr("62.72.137.109")}, [16]) = 96
close(5)                                = 0
close(6)                                = 0
write(1, "hops: 3 address 62.72.137.109 \n", 31) = 31
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 5
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_ICMP) = 6
setsockopt(5, SOL_IP, IP_TTL, [4], 4)   = 0
setsockopt(6, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8) = 0
bind(6, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(39554), sin_addr=inet_addr("0.0.0.0")}, 16) = 0
sendto(5, "hello", 5, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(40066), sin_addr=inet_addr("204.79.197.200")}, 16) = 5
recvfrom(6, "E\0\0`{\v\0\0\374\1\271?>H\211m\300\250\1\364\v\0B/?\363\307\260E\0\0!"..., 512, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(0), sin_addr=inet_addr("62.72.137.109")}, [16]) = 96
close(5)                                = 0
close(6)                                = 0
write(1, "hops: 4 address 62.72.137.109 \n", 31) = 31
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 5
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_ICMP) = 6
setsockopt(5, SOL_IP, IP_TTL, [5], 4)   = 0
setsockopt(6, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8) = 0
bind(6, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(39554), sin_addr=inet_addr("0.0.0.0")}, 16) = 0
sendto(5, "hello", 5, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(40066), sin_addr=inet_addr("204.79.197.200")}, 16) = 5
recvfrom(6, "E\0\0`\2263\0\0\374\1\240\276>H\206\306\300\250\1\364\v\0I\302\0\21\0\0E\0\0!"..., 512, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(0), sin_addr=inet_addr("62.72.134.198")}, [16]) = 96
close(5)                                = 0
close(6)                                = 0
write(1, "hops: 5 address 62.72.134.198 \n", 31) = 31
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 5
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_ICMP) = 6
setsockopt(5, SOL_IP, IP_TTL, [6], 4)   = 0
setsockopt(6, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8) = 0
bind(6, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(39554), sin_addr=inet_addr("0.0.0.0")}, 16) = 0
sendto(5, "hello", 5, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(40066), sin_addr=inet_addr("204.79.197.200")}, 16) = 5
recvfrom(6, "E\0\0008\0\0\0\0\373\1YY\303B\340\214\300\250\1\364\v\0\215\245\0\0\0\0E\0\0!"..., 512, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(0), sin_addr=inet_addr("195.66.224.140")}, [16]) = 56
close(5)                                = 0
close(6)                                = 0
write(1, "hops: 6 address 195.66.224.140 \n", 32) = 32
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 5
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_ICMP) = 6
setsockopt(5, SOL_IP, IP_TTL, [7], 4)   = 0
setsockopt(6, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8) = 0
bind(6, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(39554), sin_addr=inet_addr("0.0.0.0")}, 16) = 0
sendto(5, "hello", 5, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(40066), sin_addr=inet_addr("204.79.197.200")}, 16) = 5
recvfrom(6, "E\0\0008\376j@\0\371\0016\271\203\375\6\7\300\250\1\364\v\0\215\245\0\0\0\0E\0\0!"..., 512, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(0), sin_addr=inet_addr("131.253.6.7")}, [16]) = 56
close(5)                                = 0
close(6)                                = 0
write(1, "hops: 7 address 131.253.6.7 \n", 29) = 29
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 5
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_ICMP) = 6
setsockopt(5, SOL_IP, IP_TTL, [8], 4)   = 0
setsockopt(6, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8) = 0
bind(6, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(39554), sin_addr=inet_addr("0.0.0.0")}, 16) = 0
sendto(5, "hello", 5, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(40066), sin_addr=inet_addr("204.79.197.200")}, 16) = 5
recvfrom(6, 0xbff3ab4c, 512, 0, 0xbff3ab2c, 0xbff3aae0) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
write(1, "no data receievd\n", 17)      = 17
close(5)                                = 0
close(6)                                = 0
write(1, "hops: 8 address 131.253.6.7 \n", 29) = 29
```

it repeatedly goes through and repeats the last recvfrom here.

Comment: Please update the code snippet accordingly, too

Comment: Can you run your binary with `strace` and provide the line where it hangs?

Comment: I edited the question so that the strace is now in there too

Comment: Hm, looks like it works like expected, you just don't get any unreachables from hop 7 on. Maybe the target host is on hop 7 and does not generate `port unreachable`-packets for your UDP-probes. If you are still in doubt, use tcpdump to see if packets arrive, but I don't believe so.

Comment: I have admitted defeat for now, perhaps some sleep will give me some clarity. If not I will have to leave as an imperfect solution while i work on other aspects of this project.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that the hop in question doesn't generate `ICMP_TIMXCEED` messages.

There are several reasons why this may happen:

- rate limited by the hop
- administratively disabled
- filtered somewhere else in the path

You'll need to implement a "read timeout" in your raw socket handler to detect that, most easily using `setsockopt(recvsock, SO_TIMEOUT, ...)`

Comment: I see, would you mind elaborating more on that? would it simply be a case of adding another setsocketopt for the sending socket with a timeout value?

Comment: @PaddyOsmond  I haven't tried it with raw sockets, but I would expect that to be the right way to do it   (but on the reading socket, not the sending socket)

Answer (score 1):

The hops are not guaranteed to send ICMP unreachable messages, some don't at all and some have a strict rate limit for generation of such messages.

Furthermore, the target may throw away the probe packet without replying, so you do not know when the target is reached (i.e. ttl > number of hops).

So you have to implement a timeout with `select()` or `(e)poll()` to continue sending your probes if one hop has timeouted.

Apart from that, a better way would be to set `IP_RECVERR` on the socket, use `recvmsg()` for reading and get the icmp errors from the error queue of the socket. This should even run without root privileges because you only need the UDP- and no raw-socket. But still you will have to implement a read-timeout.

Comment: there's no need to use `select()` or `poll()` unless handling multiple packets in-transit at the same time.  A simple read-timeout on the socket should suffice.   Good idea about `IP_RECVERR`, though, assuming it's portable.

Comment: I don't see any sign of `IP_RECVERR` on BSD-derived systems